# Binding mismatch in wsdl and config file

Tags: wcf, iis-7, wcf-binding

I have an unique problem. I have hosted a WCF service with wsHttpBinding. The server.config file with the binding configuration is given below:

```
<system.serviceModel>
     <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="SafeSerice.ServiceBehavior" name="NEPLANWEBV18.1.Services.External.NeplanService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="NEPLANWEBV18.1.External.INeplanService" bindingConfiguration="SafeServiceConf">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
         <binding name="SafeServiceConf" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="01:20:00" sendTimeout="01:20:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483646" maxBytesPerRead="65536" maxStringContentLength="2147483646" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

However after hosting it in IIS 7.0, when I browse and view the WSDL, the binding comes as:

```
<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_NeplanService" type="i0:NeplanService">
```

Where am i making a mistake? For this service I require wsHttpBinding. 
I would be really grateful if anyone can shed some light into this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer after long hours of confusion. I had given the service name wrong. Since it was unable to find the service it defaulted to basichttp binding.